# Angular Material elements are not known element error

Tags: angular, angular11

I have a dashboard component in an Angular project that utilizes Angular Material elements like so:

```html
<mat-card fxFlex fxFill>
  <mat-card-title fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <span class="mat-title">My Dashboard</span>
  </mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
```

And all the Angular Material components are giving me this error of no known element error. I thought perhaps I needed to import the `MatCardModule` into the app routing module and then export it but that did nothing, so I am unsure what is behind this error.

The error says:

```
'mat-card-title' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-card-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: What the error is?

Comment: Do you already follow all those step: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using a lazy loaded module, if the import of `MatCardModule` didn't work on the component, so you need to go to the module where the component is declared inside `declarations` and then add the `MatCardModule` inside the imports of that module. An alternative, is to create a shared module called `MaterialModule` where you import all the needed material modules and import inside the individual lazy loaded modules for usage.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I first set up Angular Material I put the module in declarations and not imports, which can cause this problem. I ran build and it threw the error, I looked over the code and saw the mistake. Once I moved the module to the imports everything worked.